# I'm trying sort in powerapps but it's giving me errors

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I'm using this onChange in fluent UI creatorkit detailsList connected with sharepoint list,

```
ClearCollect(
    MyDataSource,
    SortByColumns(MyDataSource, If(SortAsc, SortColumn, SortColumn & " desc"))
);
```

when I play and try to sort it gives me the error, The specified column does not exists or an invalid sort column type,
I'm new to this please help me resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ClearCollect(
    MyDataSource,
    SortByColumns(MyDataSource, SortColumn, If(SortAsc, SortOrder.Ascending, SortOrder.Descending))
);
```

The syntax `SortByColumns` for is:

```
SortByColumns(DATA_SOURCE, COLUMN_1, SORT_FOR_COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, SORT_FOR_COLUMN_2)
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-sort